# How to add numbers/value together to a value based on keywords using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a small project but I'm stuck and don't even know where to begin with the JS code. Essentially when you type in your order in the textbox, as you type it or when you click the button (it doesn't have to add everything up in real time though it would be "cooler") it adds a number to the price based on what word is detected, so if soup is 5 dollars for example and a drink 2 and you write both, it'll add the two prices up based on your order. I thought about creating an array (I'm not too good with those) and I could just assign a number to it with the => thingy, but then how would I apply it the textarea on key up or the button to add up based on what word from array (and its' number) is detected as input and then add the numbers associated with the non number array? I thought about doing a function for each word and if that word is in the box it just adds a number that is the price to the price tag below it but that would 30 else if statements and I don't know if that would be beneficial as I want to learn something new that I haven't tried before and an else if statement but mess up and not add certain words and only add 2 prices instead of however many. Maybe a foreach function?

Here is the HTML & CSS: https://codepen.io/Filizof/pen/zyRvOG?editors=1010

```css
body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  text-align: center;
}
#menudiv {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 4px dashed white;
}
#menutitle {
  color: white;
  background: #7b2302;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 21px;
}
#menutext {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -55px;
  font-family: papyrus;
}
.listitem {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: papyrus;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#orderdiv {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  position: relative;
  top: -1008px;
  right: -550px;
  border: 4px dashed white;
}
#ordertitlediv {
  background: #7b2302;
  color: white;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
}
#ordertext {
  font-family: papyrus;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -18px;
}
.listorderitem {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#firstitem {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -60px;
}
#orderlist {
  position: relative;
  right: 220px;
  top: -50px;
}
#txtarea {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-family: papyrus;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.takelist {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 60px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  font-family: papyrus;
}
#mybtn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-family: papyrus;
}
```

```html
<div id="menudiv">
  <div id="menutitle"><p id="menutext">FILIP'S BAKEHOUSE<p/></div>
  <ul id="foodlist">
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glamour.com%2Fphotos%2F57597064f4c7c09c2559f60e%2Fmaster%2Fw_1024%2Cc_limit%2Fcarrot-soup.png&f=1">Soup: $5</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fcentra.ie%2Fimage%2Fvar%2Ffiles%2FADF%2FLoveDinner%2FCentra_honey_sauce_noodles.png&f=1">Noodles: $5</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F08%2FPNGPIX-COM-Bread-PNG-Transparent-Image.png&f=1">Bread: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Ftea%2Ftea_PNG16896.png&f=1">Tea: $1.50</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pizzainn-me.com%2Fcontent%2Fthemes%2Fbernelli%2Fimg%2Fappetizers%2Flasagna.png&f=1">Lasagna: $6</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2F78.media.tumblr.com%2F32f23f3391e3b515d6b430b895458f9c%2Ftumblr_ns6b039Uzg1uyxczto1_500.png&f=1">Mousaka: %6</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Fcake%2Fcake_PNG13111.png&f=1">Cake: $4</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngall.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F05%2FSalad-PNG-Image.png&f=1">Salad: $4</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.govegan.org.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F11%2Ffruitsalad300x3007.png&f=1">Fruit Salad: $4</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="http://miam-images.m.i.pic.centerblog.net/0837921e.png">Orange Juice: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngonly.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F05%2FApple-Juice-PNG-Picture.png&f=1">Apple Juice: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pkdrecipes.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2010%2F09%2F032411-Cranberry-Juice-400.png&f=1">Cranberry Juice: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimg15.deviantart.net%2Fddeb%2Fi%2F2013%2F329%2F3%2Fe%2Fcookie__png_by_darksideofgraphic-d6vlc5l.png&f=1">Cookies: $3</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Fbiscuit%2Fbiscuit_PNG88.png&f=1">Biscuits: $3</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F07%2FPNGPIX-COM-Ice-Cream-PNG-Transparent-Image.png&f=1">Ice Cream: $3</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F11%2FPNGPIX-COM-Potato-Chips-PNG-Transparent-Image.png&f=1">Chips: $1</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fselflender.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fblog%2Ftacos_1.png&f=1">Tacos: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpluspng.com%2Fimg-png%2Ffree-png-jelly-free-range-snack-co-452.png&f=1">Jelly: $1</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fbodyfuelcafe.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F07%2FTHMB-Mango-Smoothie.png&f=1">Smoothie: $1</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F37.media.tumblr.com%2F605762b2e80fbdda35364d5b0db4a540%2Ftumblr_n5bxf2lI5k1rx3d1wo1_r2_500.png&f=1">Pancakes: $8</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F10%2FPNGPIX-COM-Sandwich-PNG-Transparent-Image-500x282.png&f=1">Sandwich: $4</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Fburger_sandwich%2Fburger_sandwich_PNG4114.png&f=1">Burger: $5</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Ffries%2Ffries_PNG77.png&f=1">Fries: $7</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F10%2FPNGPIX-COM-Almond-Nut-PNG-Image-500x404.png&f=1">Nuts: $3</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpluspng.com%2Fimg-png%2Frice-png-rice-png-601.png&f=1">Rice: $8</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpruebeydisfrute.files.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F09%2Fchai-latte.png&f=1">Chai</li>
  </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="orderdiv">
  <ul id="orderlist">
  <li id="firstitem" class="listorderitem"><img id="orderimg" height="100" width="100" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.pixabay.com%2Fphoto%2F2016%2F09%2F13%2F18%2F38%2Fsilverware-1667988__340.png&f=1"></li>
    <li class="listorderitem"><div id="ordertitlediv"><p id="ordertext">DM YOUR ORDER</p></div></li>
  </ul>
  <textarea id="txtarea" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  <ul id="takeorderlist">
    <li class="takelist">$<p id="price"></p></li>
    <li class="takelist"><p id="wall">|</p></li>
    <li class="takelist"><button id="mybtn">ORDER</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
create array w/ foods and a numbered price
create variables for the txtarea in the html
create the function (maybe foreach) that adds the price of each word
```

Comment: Please provide CODE of what you have tried already.

Comment: What about user clicks on food images and picks the amount?

Comment: You could make an array of objects in format `{ "soup": 5 }`, then make user input lowercase, split on spaces, and map according to prices array.

Comment: @fico Did you check the answer?

Comment: Yeah I did, the two answers worked, I don't understand them fully but it helped me lots.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something as follows.
Note the code below only includes mapping for `soup`, `noodles` and `bread`, but you can add the remaining items easily to the `priceMap`.
Also space is assumed as a delimiter used by a user in textarea. You can change it by passing a different character into `split`.

```
const text = document.getElementById('txtarea');
const totalPrice = document.getElementById('price');
const priceMap = {
  soup: 5,
  noodles: 5,
  bread: 2
};
text.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  totalPrice.textContent = text.value.split(' ')
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map(v => v.toLowerCase())
    .map(v => priceMap[v])
    .filter(Boolean)
    .reduce((sum, price) => sum + price, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this fully functional, you should separate order items by `,` and give quantity to the item even though you buy 1.
Try `1 lasagna, 2 cake`

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#txtarea")
let selectedFood = [];
let menu = [
 {
  item: "soup",
  price: 5
 },
 {
  item: "noodles",
  price: 5
 },
 {
  item: "bread",
  price: 2
 },
 {
  item: "tea",
  price: 1.5
 },
 {
  item: "lasagna",
  price: 6
 },
 {
  item: "mousaka",
  price: 6
 },
 {
  item: "cake",
  price: 4
 },
 {
  item: "salad",
  price: 4
 },
 {
  item: "fruit salad",
  price: 4
 },
 {
  item: "orange juice",
  price: 2
 },
 {
  item: "apple juice",
  price: 2
 },
 {
  item: "cranberry juice",
  price: 2
 },
 {
  item: "cookies",
  price: 3
 },
 {
  item: "biscuits",
  price: 3
 },
 {
  item: "ice icream",
  price: 3
 },
 {
  item: "chips",
  price: 1
 },
 {
  item: "tacos",
  price: 2
 },
 {
  item: "jelly",
  price: 1
 },
 {
  item: "smoothie",
  price: 1
 },
 {
  item: "pancakes",
  price: 8
 },
 {
  item: "sandwich",
  price: 4
 },
 {
  item: "burger",
  price: 5
 },
 {
  item: "fries",
  price: 7
 },
 {
  item: "nuts",
  price: 3
 },
 {
  item: "rice",
  price: 8
 },
 {
  item: "chai",
  price: 5
 }
];
input.onkeyup = () => {
 let selection = input.value.replace(/ /g, '').split(",")
 let total = 0;
 selection.map(s => {
 let cost = 0;
 let found = menu.filter(m => m.item == s.replace(/\d+/g, ''))
 if(found.length > 0) {
  cost = found[0].price * parseInt(s)
  total += cost;
 }
 })
 document.querySelector("#price").innerText = total;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  text-align: center;
}
#menudiv {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 4px dashed white;
}
#menutitle {
  color: white;
  background: #7b2302;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 21px;
}
#menutext {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -55px;
  font-family: papyrus;
}
.listitem {
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: papyrus;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#orderdiv {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  position: relative;
  top: -1008px;
  right: -550px;
  border: 4px dashed white;
}
#ordertitlediv {
  background: #7b2302;
  color: white;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
}
#ordertext {
  font-family: papyrus;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -18px;
}
.listorderitem {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#firstitem {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -60px;
}
#orderlist {
  position: relative;
  right: 220px;
  top: -50px;
}
#txtarea {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  font-family: papyrus;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.takelist {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 60px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  font-family: papyrus;
}
#mybtn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-family: papyrus;
}
```

```html
<div id="menudiv">
  <div id="menutitle"><p id="menutext">FILIP'S BAKEHOUSE<p/></div>
  <ul id="foodlist">
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glamour.com%2Fphotos%2F57597064f4c7c09c2559f60e%2Fmaster%2Fw_1024%2Cc_limit%2Fcarrot-soup.png&f=1">Soup: $5</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fcentra.ie%2Fimage%2Fvar%2Ffiles%2FADF%2FLoveDinner%2FCentra_honey_sauce_noodles.png&f=1">Noodles: $5</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F08%2FPNGPIX-COM-Bread-PNG-Transparent-Image.png&f=1">Bread: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Ftea%2Ftea_PNG16896.png&f=1">Tea: $1.50</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pizzainn-me.com%2Fcontent%2Fthemes%2Fbernelli%2Fimg%2Fappetizers%2Flasagna.png&f=1">Lasagna: $6</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2F78.media.tumblr.com%2F32f23f3391e3b515d6b430b895458f9c%2Ftumblr_ns6b039Uzg1uyxczto1_500.png&f=1">Mousaka: %6</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Fcake%2Fcake_PNG13111.png&f=1">Cake: $4</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngall.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F05%2FSalad-PNG-Image.png&f=1">Salad: $4</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.govegan.org.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F11%2Ffruitsalad300x3007.png&f=1">Fruit Salad: $4</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="http://miam-images.m.i.pic.centerblog.net/0837921e.png">Orange Juice: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngonly.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F05%2FApple-Juice-PNG-Picture.png&f=1">Apple Juice: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pkdrecipes.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2010%2F09%2F032411-Cranberry-Juice-400.png&f=1">Cranberry Juice: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimg15.deviantart.net%2Fddeb%2Fi%2F2013%2F329%2F3%2Fe%2Fcookie__png_by_darksideofgraphic-d6vlc5l.png&f=1">Cookies: $3</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Fbiscuit%2Fbiscuit_PNG88.png&f=1">Biscuits: $3</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F07%2FPNGPIX-COM-Ice-Cream-PNG-Transparent-Image.png&f=1">Ice Cream: $3</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F11%2FPNGPIX-COM-Potato-Chips-PNG-Transparent-Image.png&f=1">Chips: $1</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fselflender.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fblog%2Ftacos_1.png&f=1">Tacos: $2</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpluspng.com%2Fimg-png%2Ffree-png-jelly-free-range-snack-co-452.png&f=1">Jelly: $1</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fbodyfuelcafe.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F07%2FTHMB-Mango-Smoothie.png&f=1">Smoothie: $1</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F37.media.tumblr.com%2F605762b2e80fbdda35364d5b0db4a540%2Ftumblr_n5bxf2lI5k1rx3d1wo1_r2_500.png&f=1">Pancakes: $8</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F10%2FPNGPIX-COM-Sandwich-PNG-Transparent-Image-500x282.png&f=1">Sandwich: $4</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Fburger_sandwich%2Fburger_sandwich_PNG4114.png&f=1">Burger: $5</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fuploads%2Ffries%2Ffries_PNG77.png&f=1">Fries: $7</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngpix.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F10%2FPNGPIX-COM-Almond-Nut-PNG-Image-500x404.png&f=1">Nuts: $3</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpluspng.com%2Fimg-png%2Frice-png-rice-png-601.png&f=1">Rice: $8</li>
    <li class="listitem"><img height="50" width="50" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpruebeydisfrute.files.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F09%2Fchai-latte.png&f=1">Chai</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="orderdiv">
  <ul id="orderlist">
  <li id="firstitem" class="listorderitem"><img id="orderimg" height="100" width="100" src="https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.pixabay.com%2Fphoto%2F2016%2F09%2F13%2F18%2F38%2Fsilverware-1667988__340.png&f=1"></li>
    <li class="listorderitem"><div id="ordertitlediv"><p id="ordertext">DM YOUR ORDER</p></div></li>
  </ul>
  <textarea id="txtarea" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  <ul id="takeorderlist">
    <li class="takelist">$<p id="price"></p></li>
    <li class="takelist"><p id="wall">|</p></li>
    <li class="takelist"><button id="mybtn">ORDER</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```